# Error in search space while performing optuna hyperparameter optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, optuna

the code most likely containing the bug->

```py
import optuna

def objective(trial):
    

    
    criterion = trial.suggest_categorical("criterion", ["gini", "entropy"]),
    min_samples_split = trial.suggest_float('min_samples_split', 0, 1),
    max_depth = trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 3, 20, step=3),
    min_samples_leaf = trial.suggest_float('min_samples_leaf', 0, 1),
    min_impurity_decrease = trial.suggest_float('min_impurity_decrease', 0, 0.1),
    splitter = trial.suggest_categorical('splitter', ['best', 'random']),
    class_weight = trial.suggest_categorical('class_weight', [None, 'balanced'])

    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(splitter=splitter, criterion=criterion, min_samples_split=min_samples_split, max_depth=max_depth, min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, min_impurity_decrease=min_impurity_decrease, class_weight=class_weight)

    return cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1).mean()

study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize', sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler())
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=60, n_jobs=-1)

trial = study.best_trial

print('Accuracy: ', trial.value)
print('Best params: ', trial.params)
```

the error log->

```py
[I 2023-08-13 23:29:24,693] A new study created in memory with name: no-name-9880947b-61e8-4f48-9439-9598b5855f1e
[W 2023-08-13 23:29:24,949] Trial 0 failed with parameters: {'criterion': 'gini', 'min_samples_split': 0.9672704152904984, 'max_depth': 3, 'min_samples_leaf': 0.9028727486308868, 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.03168240940817766, 'splitter': 'best', 'class_weight': 'balanced'} because of the following error: ValueError('\nAll the 5 fits failed.\nIt is very likely that your model is misconfigured.\nYou can try to debug the error by setting error_score=\'raise\'.\n\nBelow are more details about the failures:\n--------------------------------------------------------
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_param_validation.py", line 97, in validate_parameter_constraints
    raise InvalidParameterError(
sklearn.utils._param_validation.InvalidParameterError: The 'criterion' parameter of DecisionTreeClassifier must be a str among {'log_loss', 'gini', 'entropy'}. Got ('gini',) instead.
```

What am i I doing wrong?

I tried commenting out the trial.suggest_categorical part for criterion variable but nothing changed.

Comment: It was resolved Thank you to all who took a moment to even look at my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas at the end of some of your statements are converting parameters to tuples. Removing the commas should fix it.